# Can a mountain catch lightning and store that energy or become conductive?

Tags: science-fiction, physics, space, civilization, electricity

Can we have a natural or man made mountain / hill of metal / ore that can catch lightning and become conductive so that it can be used as an energy source? What would be the expected energy output or storage capacity of that structure?

Comment: I don't think it will generate enough energy yield. You'll need a *lot* of bad weather above that mountain, to make up for the energy invested in it.. the average lightning strike contains the energy of a 9V battery..

Comment: Closer to 30,000 PP3s (high energy ones store about 35,000 J, a powerful lightning strike can be a GJ), still not a lot though. @Goodies

Comment: The plan is not to use it as a primary energy source. Just something to catch whatever extra can be caught. What would be the composition required for such a mountain?

Comment: Word salad is delicious, albeit meaningless. In reasonable terms, what the question is asking is how to build a battery allowing for a gigantic charging current. Sadly, we have no idea.

Comment: There are real-world examples of mountains that attract lightning, but the charges would rapidly bleed away. According to the guides on-site, construction on the giant statue of Crazy Horse has to be stopped every time the weather gets bad because the mountain is filled with iron ore and naturally attracts lightning strikes.

Comment: @A Rogue Ant , can you share even a challenged, half baked idea.

Comment: Rooting (pun intended) for you.

Comment: As strange as it may seem, I've had this tab open since my last comment, waiting for inspiration - I'll wait only a few days more, then if I've nothing new, I'll splurge out the ideas I have in the hope you can use something.

Answer (score 4):

To produce a lighting you need to accumulate charges. The lighting is the result of that accumulation of charges breaking the dielectric and flowing, therefore you are actually neutralizing that accumulation.
To store the energy of a lighting you would need a separate mechanism.

And no, a conductor cannot store electric energy, can only let it flow.

Comment: A conductor can let it flow. And that flow can then later be caught down the road. But is there a possibility to have enough concentration of naturally or man made amounts of conducting material in mountains / hills / mounds to let it catch lightning?

Comment: @mukul215: think of a lightning rod.  It lets the lightning come to earth, where it wants to be.  The charge grounds itself.  Mountains are God's lightning rods.  The lightning hits them and then is at home in the earth.  If the mountain is conductive, it is just a giant lightning rod.

Comment: @Willk , can you just hint about the mechanism required to store charge generated by the mountain? I am having difficulty knowing where to start. The scale , the tech, the means , anything ... Any small scale but comparable example from existing tech or fiction.

Comment: @mukul215 - think of a water wheel.  You want to put it in falling water to get energy.  If you put it in the pond at the bottom of the waterfall, that water will provide you no energy.  Once the lightning has hit the mountain, it is water that is in the pond.   It has escaped you.   You must catch it on the way down.  That is tricky. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvesting_lightning_energy  If you want to have a magic world you could have a giant crystal or something in the mountain that stores charge - good make believe for a story but not science.

Comment: The way to use a mountain is to erect towers or float balloons on wires and bleed down the cloud charge into a static electricity motor little by little.  Use the motors to lift water that you can later release to generate power.    More speculative reading:  https://www.halfbakery.com/idea/Lightning_20Power_20Plant#998154000